# Customizing JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

We are trying to customize a JOptionPane generated JDialog to have rounded corners. We have a JPanel implementation that has rounded corners. I am unable to find a way to integrate the rounded corners implementation into the JOptionPane/JDialog.

It would of great help if some one can point me into how I can fit the JDialog into a JPanel or some other way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

A `JDialog` is a top level component that can not be added anywhere. Although you can add the "content" of the `JOptionPane`, by using one of `JOptionPane`'s constructors .

Answer (score 2):

`JOptionPane` extends from `JComponent`.  It provides convince methods to construct the `JDialog` which is displayed on the screen (containing an instance of `JOptionPane`)

If you want to modify the look and feel of the `JDialog`, you need to create your own undecorated dialog and add the `JOptionPane` to it.

What I would suggest would be to create a number of `static` utility methods that mimic the `JOptionPane` `showXxxMessage` methods but which create the instance of the dialog you want and which then simply add an instance of the `JOptionPane` to.

You will need to attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JOptionPane` to monitor when the user makes a selection though.